# How do you say “examenes extraordinarios”

Tags: meaning

So in mexico when you fail a class such a math you have to make up for it by going to a whole week of courses in winter break or summer and then you redo the exam, so this semester I failed chemistry and I say “Me voy a ir a extraordinarios”, is there a specific way to say that in English because I’ve never heard someone say “im going to extraordinaries”

Comment: In the UK, we usually call them *re-sits* - "I'm going to take my re-sits". I don't know if there is a more formal academic term.

Answer (score 5):

As Mick says in his comment, in the UK there is such a system that may not have a formal term.  Since (in BrE) you *sit* an exam, these might be informally called **re-sits** of an exam.

In AmE we usually say "take" an exam.  Also the big test at the end of a course is called a "final exam" or just a "final". So, perhaps the best translation would be something like:

> I'm going to **re-take** my (History) **final**.

In the US some schools might have such a system; however the most common remedy for when you fail a class is you have to *re-take* the entire course.  You do this either the next semester or over the summer.  This is called *summer school*, which most students would prefer not to do because, ordinarily, summer is vacation time.

> I have to **re-take** History **over the summer**.
>
> I have to go to **summer school** to **make up for** failing History this semester.

Of course, some students use summer school to get ahead of their studies so they can graduate more quickly (or focus on other, more interesting classes during the school year) but that's a different situation.

Answer (score 0):

“Extraordinarios” would come close to theliteral meaning of English “extraordinary,” literally “not ordinary,” or “beyond what is ordinary.”

Extraordinarios are not ordinary exams, they are taken after regular exams to “make up” for a poor grade. So in English we may call them “make-up exams,” or in the singular, a “make-up exam,” which you take after additional “make-up classes.”

You might also call them “remedial classes” and a “remedial exam,” as they remedy the problem of the original grade.